# How do I read the text displayed on browser using a Flutter chrome extension?

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, flutter-web

So basically what I want to do is use a Flutter Chrome extension to be able to read the content being displayed by a webpage. I understand that the underlying text is more than likely not extractable directly from the underlying JS, so I simple want to be able to read what is being displayed

Is there any way to do this? I am not a web developer, so I would prefer flutter only solutions

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes I did.  Friend wrote some basic JS to manipulate the DOM

Comment: A deleted answer suggests that it might be helpful to post the code as a self-answer so that others can use it.